# When to use Never

Tags: swift, error-handling

I came across Swift's `Never` type, and the documentation gives the following hypothetical sample code:

```
func crashAndBurn() -> Never {
    fatalError("Something very, very bad happened")
}
```

I understand the concept of `Never` but can't really think of a practical use case in a real world application.

Does anyone have an example of how they've used `Never`?

Comment: Right you are! Thanks :-)